# Updating cart with ajax - Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am using ajax to updat codeigniter cart

below is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>update-shopping-cart",
            data: $("#columnarForm").serialize(),
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="<?php echo site_url('assets/images/loading.gif'); ?>" class="center-block" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

My controller

```
// Updated the shopping cart
        function updateCart(){
        $data = array(
               'rowid'   => $this->input->post('rowid'),
               'qty'     => $this->input->post('qty'),
        );

        // Update the cart with the new information
        $this->cart->update($data);
        redirect(base_url().'update-cart-view');
        }
```

my problem is when i add multiple items in the cart & update the quantity of items the quantity does not change. It only works for the last item added.

Please help.

Comment: Can you share the view that this appears in? You might be passing in the wrong row id, which would cause the update to keep happening but only on one of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with row id.
You need to find out  row id of that product in the cart 
then update

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are grabbing correct rowid when updating the particular item in cart because when there are multiple items you cant be sure about which id to update, else that will update qty of each item.

First thing when you are updating the cart you need to pass rowid as below from your view

```
    <?php if($cart=$this->cart->contents()):?>
    <?php foreach ($cart as $item): ?>
    <input type="hidden" name='' id='rowid' value='<?=$item['rowid']?>'>
<ul>
<li><?=$item['name']?></li>
</ul>

    <?php endforeach ?>
    <?php endif;?>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var rowid=$("#rowid").val();
        $("#addToCart").click(function(){
        $("#result").show();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>shop/update",
            data: {"rowid":rowid},
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#result').html('<img src="<?=base_url()?>assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" class="center-block" />');
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert("done! here update your cart items as per data received with jquery using .html tag");
                $("#result").hide();
            },
            error: function(data){
     alert("inside error");
            }
        });
        });
        })

</script>
```

Second thing what I observed is you are redirecting after update in controller, but ajax does not works when you redirect, ajax simply executes the query and returns back so in your controller please do following trick.

```
public function update(){
        $rowid=$this->input->post('rowid');
        $cart=$this->cart->contents();
        foreach ($cart as $cart) {
//now match your item whose qty is updated
              if($rowid==$cart['rowid']){
            $qty=$cart['qty'];
        }
        }

                  $data=array(
                        'rowid'=>$rowid,
                        'qty'=>$qty+1
                        );
                  $data=$this->cart->update($data);
                  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Then You would have answered your own question. so that nobody will attempt to ans it, anyway bye.